# checking for undefined in ! condition

Tags: javascript

I am checking whether the `object` contains user property and the user array first details `object` has a `property` or not.

```
if (a.obj.twitter['user'] && Array.isArray(a.obj.twitter['user'])
                    && a.obj.twitter['user'][0] && a.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop]
                    && !b.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop]) {
```

Should i do the same when i am checking for `! too?` Is there a better way?

```
!b.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop]
```

Comment: If `b` may not contain the full property depth through `details`, then you'd need to check it if you don't want it to throw an error.

Comment: `a.obj.twitter['user']` is redundant. `Array.isArray` returns false for `undefined`

Comment: Also, you didn't check existance of `details` key

Comment: @vp_arth: I'm guessing his API provides `.details` consistently when there's a `user` object. Good point about `a.obj.twitter['user']`.

Comment: @squint: can you show me an example of the same...

Comment: `&& !(b.obj.twitter['user'] && b.obj.twitter['user'][0] && b.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop])` *(Notice the outer parens.)* Though this whole thing is pretty messy, so I'd be tempted to make a function that looks to see if the prop exists. Then it would just be like: `if (hasProp(a, prop) && !hasProp(b, prop)) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Should i do the same when i am checking for ! too?"*

Yes and it would be written out the same way except in parens with the `!` before the opening paren:

```
if (a.obj.twitter['user'] &&
    Array.isArray(a.obj.twitter['user']) &&
    a.obj.twitter['user'][0] &&
    a.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop] &&

    !(b.obj.twitter['user'] &&
      Array.isArray(b.obj.twitter['user']) &&
      b.obj.twitter['user'][0] &&
      b.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop])) {
```

but...

> *"Is there a better way?"*

I think this is worth rolling out into a separate function, just to keep things readable.

You could do something like:

```
function hasProp(o, prop) {
  return !!(o.obj.twitter['user'] &&
            Array.isArray(o.obj.twitter['user']) &&
            o.obj.twitter['user'][0] &&
            o.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop])
}
```

Then it's just:

```
if (hasProp(a, prop) && !hasProp(b, prop)) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this check in `try catch` block

```js
b= {};
function f() {
  try {
    return b.obj.twitter['user'][0].details[prop]
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(f());
```